# Why isn't this command block (the one circled in red) working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

[image]

The command on this command block is:

```
 /execute if entity @a[x=-519.5,y=141.0,z=-258.5,dx=0,dy=0,dz=0] run bossbar set minecraft:protectorbar visible true
```

I have another command block that has the command:

```
/execute if entity @a[x=-519.5,y=141.0,z=-258.5,dx=0,dy=0,dz=0] run bossbar set minecraft:protectorbar players @a
```

So when I go to the coordinates in that command, the bossbar should be visible. If I put the command:

```
/bossbar set minecraft:protectorbar visible true
```

in myself it works, the command block is powered on, and the other command blocks all work too, so I don't know why this one wouldn't work.

Comment: Notice that in your last question I specifically set the position inside the x and z coordinates to `x.0` instead of `x.5`. But at best that would slightly move the detection area over, not mess up the entire command. Have you tried replacing the `bossbar set` command with a `say` command to see if it's a problem with the execute or the bossbar command?

Comment: yeah, I swapped it with say and it didn't work. Im just confused because I have another command block with 
/execute if entity @a[x=-519.5,y=141.0,z=-258.5,dx=0,dy=0,dz=0] run tp BJONK_BJONK -513 142 -262
And that one is working

Comment: ahaaaaa - that might as well be why. If that other commandblock is working as intended, and you're testing with the BJONK_BJONK player, then the issue is probably that that commandblock runs first, teleporting the player away from that place and then the subsequent commandblocks cannot find a player there anymore. To ensure that commandblocks run in the expected order, use chain commandblocks (the green ones).

Comment: That's a great idea thank you so much!